# How to join big dataframes in Spark SQL? (best practices, stability, performance)

Tags: performance, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting the same error than [Missing an output location for shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901123/org-apache-spark-shuffle-metadatafetchfailedexception-missing-an-output-locatio) when joining big dataframes in Spark SQL. The recommendation there is to set **MEMORY_AND_DISK** and/or **spark.shuffle.memoryFraction 0**. However, spark.shuffle.memoryFraction is deprecated in Spark >= 1.6.0 and setting MEMORY_AND_DISK shouldn't help if I'm not caching any RDD or Dataframe, right? Also I'm getting lots of other WARN logs and task retries that lead me to think that the job is not stable.

Therefore, my question is:

- **What are best practices to join huge dataframes in Spark SQL >= 1.6.0?**

More specific questions are:

- How to tune **number of executors** and **spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** to achieve better stability/performance?
- How to find the right balance between **level of parallelism** (num of executors/cores) and **number of partitions**? I've found that increasing the num of executors is not always the solution as it may generate **I/O reading time out** exceptions because of network traffic.
- Is there any other relevant parameter to be tuned for this purpose?
- My understanding is that joining data stored as **ORC** or **Parquet** offers better performance than text or Avro for join operations. Is there a significant difference between Parquet and ORC?
- Is there an advantage of **SQLContext** vs **HiveContext** regarding stability/performance for join operations?
- Is there a difference regarding performance/stability when the dataframes involved in the join are previously **registerTempTable()** or **saveAsTable()**?

So far I'm using [this is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37849488/2482894) and [this chapter](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html) as a starting point. And there are a few more stackoverflow pages related to this subject. Yet I haven't found a comprehensive answer to this popular issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer is recommending to set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions above 2000 when there are shuffling memory issues, as Spark uses a different data structure for shuffle book-keeping when the number of partitions is greater than that threshold: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36459198/2482894

Comment: Setting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 is recommended in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33118489/2482894

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That are a lot of questions. Allow me to answer these one by one:

Your number of executors is most of the time variable in a production environment. This depends on the available resources. The number of partitions is important when you are performing shuffles. Assuming that your data is now skewed, you can lower the load per task by increasing the number of partitions.
A task should ideally take a couple of minus. If the task takes too long, it is possible that your container gets pre-empted and the work is lost. If the task takes only a few milliseconds, the overhead of starting the task gets dominant.

The level of parallelism and tuning your executor sizes, I would like to refer to the excellent guide by Cloudera: https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

ORC and Parquet only encode the data at rest. When doing the actual join, the data is in the in-memory format of Spark. Parquet is getting more popular since Netflix and Facebook adopted it and put a lot of effort in it. Parquet allows you to store the data more efficient and has some optimisations (predicate pushdown) that Spark uses.

You should use the SQLContext instead of the HiveContext, since the HiveContext is deprecated. The SQLContext is more general and doesn't only work with Hive.

When performing the `registerTempTable`, the data is stored within the SparkSession. This doesn't affect the execution of the join. What it stores is only the execution plan which gets invoked when an action is performed (for example `saveAsTable`). When performining a `saveAsTable` the data gets stored on the distributed file system.

Hope this helps. I would also suggest watching our talk at the Spark Summit about doing joins: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zg7NTw-kTQ. This might provide you some insights.

Cheers, Fokko

Comment: I have been looking for you ever since I saw your presentation on Iterative Broadcast join. That was really nice. I was able to perform sort merge join with two large dataframe in batches and seems working fine. link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524062/efficient-pyspark-join/53720497#53720497 ..

Comment: I wanted to use the same technique with iterative broadcast join but was not able to get that how to clear broadcast partition from memory before we broadcast the next batch of small dataframe. Could you please give your valuable inputs for below question.   see link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784272/broadcast-hash-join-iterative/56092295#56092295 .. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: any help! I am struggling to code the iterative broadcast hash join