# how to run sc.textFile() inside a foreach loop and do a union on it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

so this is what I have been trying and I'm a newbie here working with spark!

I'm trying to execute this code

```
val ii=sc.parallelize(Seq(("e.txt"),("r.txt"))).foreach{i => sc.textFile(i)}
```

but I'm getting "Nullpointer exception"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add multiple files to the `sc.textFile`. You should not use the `sc` inside of a map operation. The `map` function will be distributed to the different executors, and the `sc` lives in the driver. Therefore it will throw a Nullpointer exception.

`a.txt contents:`

```
a.txt:line1
a.txt:line2
```

`b.txt contents:`

```
b.txt:line1
b.txt:line2
```

Spark allows you to add more files in the same operation:

```
scala> sc.textFile("a.txt,b.txt").collect()
res1: Array[String] = Array(a.txt:line1, a.txt:line2, b.txt:line1, b.txt:line2)
```

Hope this helps and have fun with Spark!

Comment: sc.textFile("a.txt,b.txt").collect()  this syntax reads the file sequentially,, i need to do it in parallel fashion

Comment: It will execute in parallel. If you open the Spark UI you will see that two tasks are created. When you add more files, the number of tasks will increase.

Comment: i cant see any multiple task generated

Comment: What is your datasource?

Comment: can u take a look at this link?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286656/spark-executor-memory-exceeds-physical-limit?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I've posted my two cents :)

Comment: @AbuTahir zip files are not splittable and is a very bad input format. Perhaps you ment gzip? This is more common, but also not splittable. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208051/when-are-files-splittable

Comment: i'm trying to unzip 17 files and perform some processing , i want to unzip each of  them as separate task just wanted to make thinks efficient. and suggest me a good book on spark to dig deep