# SPARK: YARN kills containers for exceeding memory limits

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We're currently encountering an issue where Spark jobs are seeing a number of containers being killed for exceeding memory limits when running on YARN.

```
16/11/18 17:58:52 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 53.0 in stage 49.0 (TID 32715, XXXXXXXXXX): 
  ExecutorLostFailure (executor 23 exited caused by one of the running tasks) 
  Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 12.4 GB of 12 GB physical memory used. 
    Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

The following arguments are being passed via spark-submit:

```
--executor-memory=6G
--driver-memory=4G
--conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=6G"`
```

I am using Spark 2.0.1.

We have increased the memoryOverhead to this value after reading several posts about YARN killing containers (e.g. [How to avoid Spark executor from getting lost and yarn container killing it due to memory limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840492/how-to-avoid-spark-executor-from-getting-lost-and-yarn-container-killing-it-due)).

Given my parameters and the log message it does seem that "Yarn kills executors when its memory usage is larger than (executor-memory + executor.memoryOverhead)".

It is not practical to continue increasing this overhead in the hope that eventually we find a value at which these errors do not occur. We are seeing this issue on several different jobs. I would appreciate any suggestions as to parameters I should change, things I should check, where I should start looking to debug this etc. Am able to provide further config options etc.

Comment: Do you use Spark SQL?

Comment: When you use huge Datasets, then you can try to increase `spark.default.parallelism` and  `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` in `spark-defaults.conf` to a higher value. This would reduce the memory usage.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a go

Comment: Well, Spark 2.x definitely uses more off-heap memory than before so memoryOverhead needs to be set a lot higher than what we have been used to. I used to go by the rule that if my memoryOverhead had to be set to more than 1/3 of my available memory, something was wrong and I needed to repartition my data, but nowadays we have jobs running with memoryOverhead taking 2/3 of available memory, leaving only a small fraction for executor-memory. I'm afraid that all our memory settings are based to some extend on trial-and-error and intuition though...

Comment: We had that issue too, and we solved that changing to spark dynamic allocation. Just adding 2G as overhead.

Comment: @SimonSchiff - that did the trick! If you put it in a answer I'll accept it

Comment: I have put it in a answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can reduce the memory usage with the following configurations in `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.default.parallelism
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
```

And there is a difference when you use more than 2000 partitions for `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`. You can see it in the code of spark on Github:

```
private[spark] object MapStatus {

  def apply(loc: BlockManagerId, uncompressedSizes: Array[Long]): MapStatus = {
    if (uncompressedSizes.length > 2000) {
      HighlyCompressedMapStatus(loc, uncompressedSizes)
    } else {
      new CompressedMapStatus(loc, uncompressedSizes)
    }
}
```

I recommend to try to use more than 2000 Partitions for a test. It could be faster some times, when you use very huge datasets. And according to [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-usage-of-reduce-tasks) your tasks can be short as 200 ms. The correct configuration is not easy to find, but depending on your workload it can make a difference of hours.